# Can PHP's (float) casting ever return a non-float value?

Tags: php, casting, floating-point

I'm debugging some code and the previous developer wrote:

```php
if (!is_float((float)$value)) {
  throw new \Exception();
}
```

In the below table `R` is the result of converting the `VALUE` with the specified `TYPE` to `(float)`. `x` means different values are possible here.

```
R     TYPE VALUE
-     ---- -----
0          null
0     bool false
1     bool true
x      int x
x    float x
0   string 'invalid'
x   string 'x'
0    array []
1    array [x]
1   object x (raises a notice)
x resource handle (unintuitive)
```

I haven't been able to find any value that can't be converted to `(float)`. Is it at all possible for the above `\Exception` to be thrown?

[The PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.casting) says:

> ### Converting to float
>
> For information on converting strings to float, see String conversion to numbers. For values of other types, **the conversion is performed by converting the value to integer first and then to float**. See Converting to integer for more information. As of PHP 5, a notice is thrown if an object is converted to float.

(emphasis mine)

So as far as I can tell, the above `\Exception` is unreachable code. Is this correct or did the other developer know something I don't?

Comment: It was probably just defensive programming -- he wasn't sure so he added the check.

Comment: Most likely (like 99%) unreachable code. Explicit typecasting (in any language for that matter) should never return a value that isn't of the target type, barring a (pretty bad) bug. And if it doesn't, it should always raise a fatal error/exception. The only exception to that should be nullable casts, that some languages use (C#, I think), or allow (Kotlin). I believe there's a RFC proposal for this in PHP, btw.

Comment: @Jeto there is an `(unset)` cast in PHP but it's been deprecated in PHP 7 and will be removed in PHP 8.

Comment: @CJDennis Forgot that thing existed :) Although, in that case the target type was always `null`, so the target object's type's enforcing rule still applied.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible currently.

However this may change.

The reason for that is that the conversion to integer from array and (non-stringable) objects is technically undefined behaviour, see the documentation on casting to integer. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

As arrays and objects currently don't throw any type errors when trying to convert to integer it means there is always an integer representation.

As an integer can always be represented by a float (and it may even overflow into a float if it's too big). This check is (currently) always false.

(Side note: the float conversion of the resource handle is just the resource handle number allocated by PHP to that resource.)